# setting a float value in a condition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

```
 if(eventRecord.byName){
        presented.text = eventRecord.byName;   
        float descPos = 50.0;
  }else{
        [presented removeFromSuperview];
        float descPos = 35.0;
  }


CGRect descFrame = CGRectMake(125, descPos, 185, descStringSize.height);
```

I'm not even sure what to do here since the whole time I've been working with objective-c has been with objects. But now, I need to set a variable with a float value depending on the condition. I'm not sure what the syntax should be.

On a side note, xcode4 has the last line as an error because descPos is undeclared. But won't it be once the condition is run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only declairing `descPos` within the scope of the `if` statement. To access the value you are setting inside the `if` block, declare it beforehand:

```
float descPos;
if(eventRecord.byName){
    presented.text = eventRecord.byName;   
    descPos = 50.0;
} else{
    [presented removeFromSuperview];
    descPos = 35.0;
}

CGRect descFrame = CGRectMake(125, descPos, 185, descStringSize.height)
```

Otherwise, the way you are doing it, the value of `descPos` is discarded as soon as the block ends (with the `}` brace).